# CQRS, DDDD in an accounting domain

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, dddd

I'm wondering how to properly model my aggregates. The domain is accounting and I have three entities: Account, AccountingEntry (should this be a value object instead?) and AccountingTransaction. The account could be say, a customer's bank account. The AccountingEntry is an entry in the account and AccountingTransaction ties several entries that constitute a single transaction (e.g. transfer from account A to account B). together.

My thinking is to model Account and AccountingTransaction as aggregates and AccountingEntry as a collection within AccountingTransaction. This is to allow the accounting transaction aggregate enforce the invariant that says all entries in a transaction must sum to zero. The entries will hold a reference to the ID of their associated accounts (this will be useful if say, we want to reverse the transaction). The accounts would not hold any references to the entries but will hold a balance.

I would use a saga to manage the process of crediting and debiting accounts transactionally.

I would like to know if I'm modeling this right.

I would also like to know how to ensure an accounting entry cannot be created that would hold a reference (ID) to an invalid (non existent) account. Should the account be used as the factory for creating the entry, passing in it's own ID?

Comment: I think you have to also make a choice between being Idealistic & Pragmatic here.  As I understand it, DDD purists demand that an entity be valid at all times.  How do you plan on doing that with your model?  How do you add entries to a transaction and keep it summing to 0 without being invalid between adding entry lines?   (i.e. credit 1000, then add debit 500, then add debit 500 to balance the transaction)  The entity will be invalid until your final entry is added?  Pragmatically speaking, you can bend the rule you are striving for and just demand the entity is valid before saving.

Comment: As far as how to prevent a reference to an invalid (non existent) account, if you are using a relational database as your store, the Database will enforce integrity for you for free.

Comment: @FrankB you could require all entries to be added at once. That way you can check they balance before doing anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the model is pretty nice. You could use Transaction as the Entry's factory(use Account as arguments) according to Martin Fowler's [Accoutning Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/accounting.pdf).